# reload file in vim without scrolling

Tags: vim, vi

Is it possible to `:e` a buffer in vim without having the scrolling adjusted?

The behavior I see: the file is reloaded followed by a `zz` (redraw with line count at center of window).  I'd like to just reload the file.

Comment: Well, you could map over `zz` or `:e` to mark your position, run the original command then and then return to that spot. But, that's ugly and I would hope there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The [anwolib plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) has a `:KeepView` command that modifies any Ex command to keep the current window layout. You can then use

```
:KeepView edit!
```

to reload while keeping the current view.

Alternatively, you can implement this yourself using `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()`.